# ASP.Net - Javascript inside AJAX UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, jscolor

I am running into an issue with running javascript from an external javascript file inside of an UpdatePanel.  I am trying to get a color picker working inside of a ListView.  The ListView is inside of an UpdatePanel.

I am using [this color picker](http://jscolor.com/).

Here is what I have narrowed it down to:

- If I use the color picker on a textbox outside of an `UpdatePanel`, it works perfectly fine through all postbacks.
- If I use the color picker on a textbox inside of an `UpdatePanel`, it works, until I do an async postback(clicking on an "EDIT" button in the ListView).  Once the `UpdatePanel` has done the postback, the textbox will no longer show the color picker when clicked.  The same occurs when the textbox is in either the `InsertItemTemplate` or `EditItemTemplate` of the ListView.

If you would like to replicate it, simply download the color picker(it's free), then add this to a webpage...

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox" CssClass="color" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

When the page loads, the color picker works fine.  When you click on the button(which does a postback), the color picker will no longer work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After an asynchronous roundtrip, any startup scripts will not be run, which is likely why it doesn't work after the AJAX callback. The color picker likely has functions which need to be executed on page load.

I've run into this so many times that I wrote a small method to register my scripts in the code-behind, which handles both async and non-async round trips. Here's the basic outline:

```
private void RegisterClientStartupScript(string scriptKey, string scriptText)
{
    ScriptManager sManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);

    if (sManager != null && sManager.IsInAsyncPostBack)
    {
        //if a MS AJAX request, use the Scriptmanager class
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), scriptKey, scriptText, true);
    }
    else
    {
        //if a standard postback, use the standard ClientScript method
        scriptText = string.Concat("Sys.Application.add_load(function(){", scriptText, "});");
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), scriptKey, scriptText, true);
    }
}
```

I actually baked the above into a base page class so that any page I'm working with can call `this.RegisterClientStartupScript(...)`. To do that, simply create a base page class and include it there (making sure to mark protected not private or your inheriting page classes won't be able access it).

With the above code, I can confidently register client scripts regardless of whether the page is doing a postback or callback. Realizing you are using external script files, you could probably modify the above method to register external scripts rather than inline. Consult the [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) class for more details, as there are several script registering methods...

Comment: Thanks. I used this method and called the `jscolor.init()` method as the `scriptText`, and it now works.

Comment: I would prefer extension method to Page class than creating a base page class. Thanks a lot for this. +1

Comment: Can you please help me understand why you put it within "Sys.Application.add_load(function(){}" when it is a standard postback. Can I use it on a page where I've not placed ScripManager control?

Comment: @KP. I think you might help me on this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826695/where-is-scriptmanager-isstartupscriptregistered-method

Comment: @Ismail: to be honest, I can't remember exactly why the add_load function was required (it's been a long time since I wrote the above method), but I do remember it had to do with the script being registered during a postback either not firing, or firing early under certain circumstances. I found the add_load solution online and it fixed it instantly so I've stuck with it.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the jscolor source code, I noticed that it initializes everything on window load.  So, you will probably need to re-init with something like this (inside the UpdatePanel):

```
function yourInit(){
   /* keep in mind that the jscolor.js file has no way to determine
      that the script has already been initialized, and you may end
      up initializing it twice, unless you remove jscolor.install();
   */

   if (typeof(jscolor) !== 'undefined'){
      jscolor.init();
   }
}
if (typeof(Sys) !== 'undefined'){
   Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler(window, "load", yourInit);
}
else{
   // no ASP.NET AJAX, use your favorite event
   // attachment method here
}
```

If you decide to put the jscolor script inside the UpdatePanel, you will also need to add something like this to the end of the jscolor.js:

```
if(Sys && Sys.Application){
   Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
}
```

Comment: "if (window.Sys ...", not "if (Sys..."

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript which allows you to "adding JavaScript from the server to a page when performing an asynchronous postback" ?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the jscolor.js code which runs to setup the color picker is only being called when your page first loads, so when the control is regenerated on the server, you lose the changes jscolor made.  Could you register some javascript to be called in your code behind so that it would call the init method on jscolor when your asynch call completed?