# JsColor losing instance after AsyncPostBack

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jscolor

I found really nice color picker [jscolor.com](http://jscolor.com/) to use instead of the one that AJAX Toolkit provides.Installation is really piece of cake but now I have trouble with AsyncPostback.
Every time any control does AsyncPostback my ColorPicker stops working,here is code:

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextColorSample" runat="server" Width="30px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextColor" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextColor_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <input type="button" class="color {valueElement:'TextColor',styleElement:'TextColorSample',hash:true,required:false}" />
```

So after postback, nothing happens anymore when I press button(picker should popup) and TextColorSample lose background Color that picker set before Postback. Can anyone explain to me what might be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: After some more digging I found a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952817/asp-net-javascript-inside-ajax-updatepanel

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with things like "ASP.NET C#". That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @ John Thanks for pointing me to it, I see so much people doing that so I thought that's the right way to format title besides tags.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this? This helped me.

```
<script>
 $(document).on('click', '#myPickerId', function () {
    var obj = $(this)[0];
    if (!obj.hasPicker) {
        var picker = new jscolor.color(obj, {});  //
        obj.hasPicker = true;
        picker.showPicker();
    }
});    
</script>
```

In my case, the picker control was dynamic because it is inside Knockout.js 'with' statement which hides and recreates the picker when it needs.

Answer (score 0):

This reinitialize/rebind the colour picket with input controls.

```
jscolor.init();
```

Call it after success of ajax call.