# Injecting javascript from a user control inside an UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, updatepanel

When the page initially renders, the `initializeControl` function is called and everything works.

When the page performs a full post-back (via a submit button), the `initializeControl` function is also called and everything works.

When there is partial post-back of the `UpdatePanel`, though, the `initializeControl` function is never called and the control stops working.

HTML:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="myScriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="myUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <uc:MyControl ID="myControl" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

User Control:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
    Dim initializeScript = String.Format("initializeControl('{0}');", ClientID)

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page),
        New Guid().ToString(), initializeScript, True)

    MyBase.Render(writer)
End Sub
```

For testing purposes, assume the `initializeControl` function is just a `debugger;` (the content of the function works fine - it's just not being called when it needs to be).

Please keep in mind that there is no way (that I know of) for the user control to know if it is inside an `UpdatePanel` or not, and there is also no way it can access the `ScriptManager` element on the parent page in server code.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I know `UpdatePanel`s are awful and should be avoided at all costs, but I am working with hundreds of consuming pages that are already using them and they can not be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely due to the fact that the page update is happening through the update panel. Startup scripts can have issues with not firing in these cases, and need to be wrapped in:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function(){ myFunctionCall(); });
```

It's the Microsoft AJAX library's way of ensuring your startup script happens when it should during MS AJAX roundtrips.

Here's an easy way to ensure all client scripts added to the page work, regardless of whether they are contained in an ajax updatepanel or not. We use this in all of our projects and it works flawlessly:

[ASP.Net - Javascript inside AJAX UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952817/asp-net-javascript-inside-ajax-updatepanel/1953122#1953122)

Comment: i snagged the function from your other answer - upon partial postback of the update panel it appears to be calling the `initializeControl` function twice - any thoughts?

Comment: I removed the `scriptText = String.Concat("Sys.Application.add_load(function(){", scriptText, "});")` from the function and it appears to be working well, thanks!

Comment: @jbabey good stuff. Yes my answer here is if you were simply going to use it in isolation. The linked question/answer is a complete solution that doesn't require you to add the `add_load` call because the code does it for you.