# Duplicate buttons in Update Panel and JavaScript Hack

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel

In reference to my question,

[Page.Unload Event inside a Update Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531944/page-unload-event-inside-a-update-panel)

I am able to make it work but I got two buttons that do partial post back and then in my script I can do what I want, but I want it to work for just one button not two of them, best thing is button I want to make this request work for is Image button whereas other button is just a simple button. This is a User Control in ASP.NET by the way.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
   // if you use jQuery, you can load them when dom is read.
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
       prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
       prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

    });        

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    }

    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
       // after update occur on UpdatePanel run the code.
       UnloadMsgBox();
    }

    function UnloadMsgBox()
    {
        alert("Message");
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have two methods, one called `button1_Click` and another called `imageButton1_Click`. We add a HiddenField to the page like so:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidIsTheButton" value="0" />
```

In our `button1_Click` method:

```
hidIsTheButton.Value = "0";
```

In our `imageButton1_Click` method:

```
hidIsTheButton.Value = "1";
```

Here, `button1_Click` refers to your standard buttons event handler and `imageButton1_Click` referes to your `ImageButton`'s event handler.

In your `EndRequest` javascript function:

```
function EndRequest(sender, args) {
   // after update occur on UpdatePanel run the code.
   var hidIsTheButton = document.getElementById('<%=hidIsTheButton.ClientID%>');
   if (hidIsTheButton.Value == "1") {
       UnloadMsgBox();
   }
}
```

Comment: @yaron The idea of the Sean is good (+1) just work it a bit and you make it work.