# Call parent page javascript from within UpdatePanel inside iFrame

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iframe, updatepanel

I have come across a issue calling javascript from within my UpdatePanel, that is within an iFrame. I can call the parent page javascript without issue from within the iFrame using parent.functionName().

This is inside my pageName.aspx.cs. (Code by KP ([ASP.Net - Javascript inside AJAX UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952817/asp-net-javascript-inside-ajax-updatepanel)))

```
protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.Page_Load(sender, e);

    StringBuilder scriptStringB = new StringBuilder();
    scriptStringB.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
    scriptStringB.Append("function CloseiFrame() {");
    scriptStringB.Append(" alert(\"CloseiFrame\");");
    scriptStringB.Append(" CloseiFrameThroughParent();");
    scriptStringB.Append("}");
    scriptStringB.Append("</script>");

    RegisterClientStartupScript("CloseiFrame", scriptStringB.ToString());
}
private void RegisterClientStartupScript(string scriptKey, string scriptText)
{
    ScriptManager sManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);

    if (sManager != null && sManager.IsInAsyncPostBack)
    {
        //if a MS AJAX request, use the Scriptmanager class
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), scriptKey, scriptText, false);
    }
    else
    {
        //if a standard postback, use the standard ClientScript method
        scriptText = string.Concat("Sys.Application.add_load(function(){", scriptText, "});");
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), scriptKey, scriptText, false);
    }
}
```

I have tried other ways, using the Microsoft way (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) for example.

In pageName.aspx it looks like this:

```
<form id="Form1" class="iFrameForm" method="post" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            ...Scripts are included here
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:imagebutton id="ExitButton" runat="server" 
                           ImageUrl="~/exit.png" 
                           AlternateText="<%$ Resources:Resource, Exit %>" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:Resource, Exit %>" OnClick="Exit_Click" >
            </asp:imagebutton>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Of course there is more in there, but these are the basics. The button is generated and at the end of the form 'action' it has "jscriptfunction=CloseiFrame".

But there is no alert, let alone the function being called. I could of course use a service to work around all of this, but I would really like to solve this issue within the pages&javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'A' solution has been found. Using the Page_Load to check if it is a postback or a normal pageload I can call on a javascript function from there.

```
protected override void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    base.Page_Load(sender, e);

    if (IsPostBack) //If it is a postback close the popup
    {
        StringBuilder scriptStringB = new StringBuilder();
        scriptStringB.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        scriptStringB.Append(" CloseiFrameThroughParent();");
        scriptStringB.Append("</script>");

        RegisterClientStartupScript("CloseiFrameThroughParent", scriptStringB.ToString());
    }
}
```

But I must say, it isn't pretty...